# How to get Only Unique node in Neo4j Query

Tags: neo4j

I scanned a small java application  and now I'm trying to run this query on neo4J

```
MATCH (n:Class)-[rel]-(cls:Class) RETURN n,cls,rel
```

the result is giving multiple nodes with the same id is there any way to get all these relations but each unique node should come once only. I did manage to get only unique through the loop but is there any way through this query itself will give unique node

Comment: how would the output look like? You want to retrieve only unique nodes, but also all relationships and the target nodes? This is impossible, because a node can have many relationships, so it will occur many times. You could return only unique nodes and their relationship ids without the target node. So how exactly would your preferred output look like?

Comment: I want NodeArray and EdgeArray, so in NodeArray each Node Should be unique, i did achieve this by using a loop but is there any way to get it from this query itself. for the above query n and cls become Node and rel become Edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a node and edge array, I would suggest the following cypher query:

```
MATCH (n:Class)
WITH collect(n) as nodeArray
MATCH (c1:Class)-[rel]->(c2:Class)
WITH nodeArray, collect([c1,rel,c2]) as edgeArray
RETURN nodeArray, edgeArray
```

You could obviously construct the edgeArray differently, but I don't know what is your preferred structure.